# Explicit wait in selenium web driver for multiple mindow

Tags: selenium

I am automating a web base tool for that i have to handle multiple windows,but there is a problem in explicit wait is not working properly,though My script is getting fail some time.
i am using below code for explicit wait.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Logout"))).click();
```

Please guide me for the same.

Comment: I don't see you waiting for a new window here, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yeah could you provide a longer snippet of your code. Currently we are guessing that you are switching to the new window. Could be an issue that the button is inside a frame.